# Is it correct to refer the Victorian Era outside of the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, victorian

Here in the UK, we refer to the "Victorians", or the era in which the "Victorians" reigned.  I recently read an article on the BBC about a story set in the United States during the Victorian Era.  Whilst this made sense from the perspective of the BBC (being a British company), it did make me wonder if the era made *any* sense outside the borders of the UK... Do other countries even recognise it as an era?  Are there equivalents?  When is it okay and not okay to refer to something in that era that is not contextually relevant?

Have tagged as [Victorian]... ;)

Comment: You occasionally see people arguing against that usage here in the US, but it's really, really common -- people will talk about Victorian architecture or Victorian fashion (which is sort of silly anyway -- she was Queen a long time and fashions changed a lot!) or just "Victorian times."

Comment: In Germany it is a common expression, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktorianisches_Zeitalter). A similar expression could be [Wilhelminische Ära or Wilhelminismus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelminische_Ära)  = Wilhelminism.

Comment: [Not in France](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/11959/what-is-the-equivalent-in-france-of-the-victorian-era) (it wouldn't be understood by people who aren't familiar with British history).

Comment: @Gilles. Though Foucault (“Nous autres, victoriens”) evidently thought otherwise. See: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/nous-autres-victoriens.2743448/

Comment: In Sweden and Norway, the later part of the Victorian era is called the "Oscarian period", after king Oscar II (reigned 1872-1907). The term has strong implications of moral hypocrisy, with one thing said in public and another done in pricate.

Comment: People do it, but it is going out of fashion, at least in the US.

Comment: I guess it depends on the country. In Eastern Europe (Hungary) eg this term is used in international settings only if it refers to something like prudish morality.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it correct? I am pleased to say that there is no authority that can deem a term correct or incorrect. There are no language police. (See Aside #1)

If you use the term Victorian Era, you will (probably) be understood.  Although Victoria was only Queen of the Commonwealth, the sun never set on her territory, and even where she did not rule, she influenced (soft power).  As a consequence, the term is **useful** - there is an entry in both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victorian_era) and [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/victorian).

The term is commonly used in several contexts (gamewriting, costuming, fiction).

For US only, we can use the terms "ante-bellum" and "post-bellum" to refer to portions of the Victorian era.

Aside #1 I will grant that there are many language police, but they are not relevant to any meaningful endeavor. Arguably *mocking the foolish* is amusing, but probably not meaningful

Aside #2 - The prudishness of Victorians is [vastly overstated](http://interestingliterature.com/2012/12/26/ten-myths-about-the-victorians/).  Arguably, one of the reasons that the English largely ignored the revolutions of 1850 is that the English "liberals" were more powerful than liberals in other countries because they had a long history of funding themselves through publication of pornography.  Greater funding meant that they had more influence, and consequently they didn't need to rebel; they just needed to use the funds provided by pornography to advance a liberal agenda.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Just how long have you been waiting to include pornography in a History:SE answer?

Comment: There are sources for those porn funding schemes? Is this true at the scale you suggest?

Comment: It will take me some time to go back and find the citations (and I'm not searching for those search terms during work hours... I'm actually not looking forward to that search)

Answer (score 5):

“Victorian” makes sense within the boundaries of the United Kingdom (as you say), but also within the boundaries of the British Empire. Remember that Victoria was “Empress of India”. Outside of the British Empire, for example in the USA, it does not really make sense, though lots of Americans do talk about the “Victorian era”, mainly in the context of discussions of sexual prudishness.

Comment: I'm curious. Whats your source for the statement that Americans talk about the Victorian era "mainly in the context of discussions of sexual prudishness"

Comment: I thought Indians (from India- to clarify) used "Victorian" as a reference to sexual prudishness. And no- I have no references except my own life experience.

Comment: @Rajib: Actually the period of American prudishness lasted only from about 1870 to 1900, the later part of the Victorian era, that is after the Civil War, the shadow of which dampened the libidos of a whole (so-called) "Missionary" generation.

Comment: In my experience, the three most common usages of the term "Victorian" in the US is to refer to a building of some sort, furniture of some sort, or clothing of some sort.   All those are far more common then references to prudishness.  This may be a regional thing, as I'm on the West Coast, were "Victorians" are common and "Antebellum" is not a word in common usage.

Comment: "in the USA, it does not really make sense, though lots of Americans do talk about the 'Victorian era'" -- which suggests rather strongly that the term "Victorian" *does* make sense to Americans.  Perhaps what you meant to say is that you believe that it *shouldn't* make sense to Americans.

Answer (score 3):

Curiously, I was in a tour of a Victorian mansion, probably the Emyln Physic House in Cape May, New Jersey (or possibly Wheatland in Lancaster, PA), and the guide used the term "Victorian" a bit differently.  As I remember the surviving decoration was dated to two periods about a decade apart and one period was described as "Victorian" and the other had a different name.

So apparently in the tour guide believed that in the history of American interior decoration the Victorian period of 1837-1901 is divided into sub periods, one of which is called "Victorian" and the others with different names.

Comment: Victorian applies to several styles of houses; this is about the only use of "Victorian" in the US; for the various types of houses see http://www.oldhouses.com/styleguide/victorians

Answer (score 2):

As both an American and an Architect, I can agree that "Victorian" is used to describe objects, designs, ideas, and themes (especially in literature) which became prevalent during the "Victorian Era," or queen Victoria's reign.

We Americans also have another term, mostly in history books, which overlaps the earlier part of her reign called "the Gilded Age" but no one really uses that outside history class.

Comment: "Gilded Age" tends to be only after the war.

Comment: The Gilded Age - don't you mean the *latter* part of Victoria's reign? The name apparently comes from Mark Twain and Charles Dudley Warner's 'The Gilded Age' (1873).

Comment: I largely concur. In my (American) experience, Victorian is used more in the subjects of architecture, literature, and sexuality; whereas the Gilded Age is used more in the subjects of economics and political history.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely appropriate to use "Victorian" in the US to refer to anything within that date range. I grew up in an 1870s house that we unequivocally called a Victorian, even though the architect was American. There are sub-categories of styles you might hear referred to as well, such as Gothic Revival architecture, or Eastlake furniture, but you'd be safe calling those "Victorian era" as an umbrella term.

I can't speak for countries outside the US, but I have a feeling it may be the same in most of the English-speaking world. For countries like Japan, however, you're better off talking about the Meji and late Edo periods.